# Installed ActiveLabel.swift and get issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I just installed ActiveLabel.swift and get HUGE error list(using xCode 6.4).

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ActiveLabel** is created for Swift 2. You are using xCode 6.4, who only support Swift 1.x. Try upgrade to xCode 7 and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of ActiveLabel and I don't program in Swift. So a quick trip to github and a search on ActiveLabel reveals the project page. The project summary says it is written in Swift 2.

But you are using Xcode 6.4. That only supports Swift 1.x.

You need to either upgrade your project to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.x (which you really should do) or you need to find a library written with Swift 1.x.

Comment: Yes, but it does not fix all of my issues. Very few actually. Maybe i am doing it wrong(?).

Comment: I don't program in Swift so I don't know what is all involved with the upgrade. But your original question has been answered. If it helped you should consider accepting the answer.